# MySQL using aliases failed

Tags: mysql

There are 3 tables.

- `user_groups` - List of user grousp (admin, user, ...)
- `permissions` - List of permissions when using the system, e.g. "access_user_management"
- `user_group_permissions` - Assignment of user groups to permissions. For example, the group "admin" has the permissions "access_system", "access_user_management", "reset_system" while the group "user" has only the permission "access_system".

Now I want to join the three tables to get the list of permissions depending on the user group ID.

```
SELECT user_groups.user_group_id, user_group_permissions.permission_id, user_groups.name, permissions.name
FROM user_groups 
INNER JOIN user_group_permissions 
    ON user_groups.user_group_id = user_group_permissions.user_group_id
INNER JOIN permissions
    ON user_group_permissions.permission_id = permissions.permission_id
WHERE user_groups.user_group_id = 1
ORDER BY user_groups.user_group_id
```

My query is working well, but I want to use aliases for simplifying. Unfortunately aliases do not work.

```
SELECT user_groups.user_group_id, user_group_permissions.permission_id, user_groups.name, permissions.name
FROM user_groups ug
INNER JOIN user_group_permissions ugp
    ON ug.user_group_id = ugp.user_group_id
INNER JOIN permissions per
    ON ugp.permission_id = per.permission_id
WHERE ug.user_group_id = 2
ORDER BY ug.user_group_id
```

But then the following error is thrown:

**Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'user_groups.user_group_id' in 'field list'.**

Its the very same syntax for aliases that I saw in tutorials. Also tried it with `as` but this is also not working.

Anyone an idea why the aliases do not work?
I am using MySQL community server 8.0.28.

Comment: use alias name instead of table name in select portion in your query...because you've used in other parts of the query except select

Comment: Yuou must use table alias, not table name. I.e. `ug.user_group_id`. After an alias is assigned the tablename is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an alias for a table, you have to replace every instance of the table name with said alias (except for the place where you set the alias, of course).

Like this:

```
SELECT ug.user_group_id, ugp.permission_id, ug.name, per.name
FROM user_groups ug
    INNER JOIN user_group_permissions ugp
        ON ug.user_group_id = ugp.user_group_id
    INNER JOIN permissions per
        ON ugp.permission_id = per.permission_id
WHERE ug.user_group_id = 2
ORDER BY ug.user_group_id
```